# Filter for ReportViewer in Winforms app

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I have a View which returns me a view of data from my SQL Server 2012 database.
One of the fields in the view is 'SprintId'.

I have a C# WinForms application, using VS2012, which has a form, and on that form is a reportViewer.

When I run it, I get the data I expect.

Now, I need to filter the SprintId column to a certain value. (So, adding a `WHERE SprintId = 37'`)

I think, adding a Parameter on the rdlc file is the right way to go.

So, I added a parameter, calling it 'SprintId', setting the 'Type' to Integer, and even setting a default value of 37.

I'm not sure where to assign this parameter as a Where clause, though. I have the parameter, but not using it. Where do I assign that parameter to the view?

Additionally, I need to set the parameter from my form.
So, I added the following code:

```
ReportParameterCollection reportParameters = new ReportParameterCollection();
reportParameters.Add(new ReportParameter("SprintId", "37"));
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters);
```

And then the default code fires right after:

```
this.vwSprintDailyBreakdownTableAdapter.Fill(this.Scrum_MasterDataSet.vwSprintDailyBreakdown);
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

However, as soon as I add the parameter code - My report is completely blank. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

I have tried Romano's code, and this is the code I am using now, but when I run it, I get a completely blank report.

```
    var result = new DataTable();
    DataRow[] res = this.Scrum_MasterDataSet.vwSprintDailyBreakdown.Select("SprintId = 37");

    foreach (DataRow row in res)
    {
        result.ImportRow(row);
    }

    this.vwSprintDailyBreakdownTableAdapter.Fill((Scrum_MasterDataSet.vwSprintDailyBreakdownDataTable)result);
    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

And get the following exception caught:
{"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataTable' to type 'vwSprintDailyBreakdownDataTable'."}

Comment: Why don't you filter the DataSet in the first place?

Comment: I'm not sure where to set the filter. Where do you apply a filter to the dataset, that can be set from my winforms application?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a second `DataTable` and use the `Select` command of your original table to "filter" your data:

```
            vwSprintDailyBreakdownDataTable result = new vwSprintDailyBreakdownDataTable();
            DataRow[] res = this.Scrum_MasterDataSet.vwSprintDailyBreakdown.Select("SprintId = 37");

            foreach (DataRow row in res)
            {
                result.ImportRow(row);
            }

            this.vwSprintDailyBreakdownTableAdapter.Fill(result);
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: I get the following error: cannot convert from 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'Scrum_Manager_UI.Scrum_MasterDataSet.vwSprintDailyBreakdownDataTable'. This is indicated on the .Fill(result) call.

Comment: Is 'Scrum_Manager_UI.Scrum_MasterDataSet.vwSprintDailyBreakdownDataTable' a Type you implemented in your project. If so, is it derived from DataTable?

Comment: No, It comes from the Data Source, which is pointing to a View called vwSprintDailyBreakdown. Scrum_MasterDataSet is the name of the Data Source.

Comment: Then try to make the DataTable "result" of type 'Scrum_Manager_UI.Scrum_MasterDataSet.vwSprintDailyBreakdownDataTable'

Comment: I have edited the question. The code compiles, but for some reason, I just get  completely blank report, and the exception: {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataTable' to type 'vwSprintDailyBreakdownDataTable'."}.

Comment: I have edited my code, too. That was what I meant with my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

What you should consider is filtering the data when retrieving it from the database.

Behind your table adapter there's an SQL statement that's executed when you call `Fill`. You can, by right clicking the section that now contains the `Fill` method, add additional methods for selecting data, for example a method called `FillFiltered`. This method should take a parameter and the select statement should account for this parameter.

Then, instead of calling `Fill` you need to call `FillFiltered(37)` and only the required information is retrieved from the database.